# Automatic Upgrade/Update Service on AWS

Tags: wcf, upgrade, automated-deploy, aws-cloudformation

I have a bunch on services deployed on AWS.

Each time I have to change something in the service, I have to manually download my WCF files from my build server (builds created by Jenkins) .. modify web.configs, create a zip file and then upload to S3 from where my instances pull the files during bootup (CloudFormation).

What is the best way to automate this process ? Can Jenkins help ? Or should I look into another tool ? Or should I be writing a simple tool using AWS SDK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jenkins to deploy to S3.  You just need to make sure you have the appropriate AWS command line tools installed on the Jenkins server.  Then you can just make a build script to deploy the completed build files into S3 (likely on successful builds only).

Comment: Sounds like a plan, going to try this out this weekend.